# Sticky sessions considering src IP and src port in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networking

I've got a lift 'n shift deployment type (i.e. by no means cloud-native) and I'd like to setup sticky sessions so that the requests keep being handled by the same pod if it's available (from the client's perspective).

```
Client --> LB --> Ingress --> Service --> Deployment
```

Due to the fact that LB does SNAT, I think `service.spec.sessionAffinityConfig.clientIP` will work, but because all the requests would be coming with the same source IP of the loadbalancer, the workload won't be truly balanced across all the pods in the deployment.

Can you think of any way to consider source IP & port pair in the sticky session behavior?

Edit 1: The deployment runs in Oracle Cloud. We're using the Oracle Cloud Loadbalancer service in plain TCP mode (i.e. OSI Layer4).

Comment: I just realized the internal LB in K8s cluster is TCP session-based, so within one TCP session, all packets arrive to the same destination pod.

Comment: You question is ambiguous. Can you be more spcecific? What LB is that? Are you deployed on some cloud? If so, what cloud? In case your last comment is the answer to your question, please post it in answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the question describes is actually a default traffic management behavior in K8s. The packets within each TCP session target the same pod. The TCP session is initiated from the certain source IP (in our case the LB) and source port (which is different for each session), and this session remains "sticky" for its whole duration.